# SQL procedure with cursor to check if values in table 1 are also in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The problem is that I'm checking if result from cursor exists in `CDN.ZamNag` table **for every iteration.** Is there any better way to check if values in table 1 are also in table 2?

Time of executing below procedure takes 1 minute and 30 seconds - I'm searching for any ideas which will make executing shorter.

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#temp_table')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #temp_table
END 

DECLARE @Seria_Nazwa VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @Magazyn_id INT
DECLARE @Magazyn_Kod varchar(15)
DECLARE @Zlozono varchar(12)
DECLARE @dzisiaj varchar(30)
SET @dzisiaj = @data --datetime = convert(datetime,DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),120)
Declare @jutro datetime = convert(datetime,DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dzisiaj),120)

CREATE TABLE #temp_Table (
seria varchar(15),
magazynkod varchar(15),
zlozono varchar(5),
data varchar(30)
)   
DECLARE @get CURSOR
------------------------------------------------------
SET @get = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Ser_Nazwa,Mag_GidNumer,Mag_Kod
    FROM CDN.Serie, CDN.Magazyny
    WHERE Mag_Kod in('1406','1407','1408')
    and SER_Nazwa like 's%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'sk%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'sa%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'st%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'su%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's14/%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's10' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's24' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's07' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's28' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's32' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's61'

    OPEN @get
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @get into @Seria_Nazwa,@Magazyn_Id,@Magazyn_Kod
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS(
        SELECT ZaN_MagNumer,Zan_ZamSeria,Zan_DataRealizacji 
        FROM CDN.ZamNag 
        WHERE 
        Zan_MagNumer = @Magazyn_Id
        and ZaN_ZamSeria = @Seria_Nazwa
        and DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) >= @dzisiaj
        AND DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) <  @jutro
        ))
    SET @zlozono = 'tak'
    ELSE SET @zlozono = 'nie'
    INSERT INTO #temp_Table VALUES(@Seria_Nazwa,@Magazyn_Kod,@Zlozono,@dzisiaj) 
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @get INTO @Seria_Nazwa,@Magazyn_Id,@Magazyn_Kod
END
CLOSE @get
DEALLOCATE @get

select * from #Temp_Table
order by seria

END
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing that (checking if values in `Table1` are or aren't in `Table2`) is typically done with a `LEFT JOIN`. Or a `RIGHT JOIN` if you want to get creative. Using a `CURSOR` in T-SQL should be you last resort!

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.[columns]
FROM [table1] t1
LEFT JOIN [table2] t2 ON t1.[key] = t2.[key]
WHERE t2.[key] IS NULL
```

---

#### Style

There are a number of accepted standards for writing T-SQL. Some people write the keywords in `ALLCAPS`, others write them in `lowercase` - which convention you chose is entirely up to you and, in the end, doesn't matter.

What **does** matter though, is **consistency**.

> ```
> and DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) >= @dzisiaj
> AND DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) <  @jutro
> ```

and

> ```
> select * from #Temp_Table
> order by seria
> ```

shouldn't be in the same script. Pick a convention, stick to it, and thank yourself later :)

One helpful convention I've adopted, is *comma-first*. This:

> ```
> SELECT ZaN_MagNumer,Zan_ZamSeria,Zan_DataRealizacji
> ```

Would look like that:

```
SELECT 
     ZaN_MagNumer
    ,Zan_ZamSeria
    ,Zan_DataRealizacji
```

This allows you to easily comment-out, remove, add or reorder columns while reducing the room for error.

Answer (score 4):

Cursors are a form of iterative processing that defies the design-goal of SQL to do set-based operations. As a general rule, if you need a cursor to do something in SQL, then you're doing it wrong, or your database design is not optimal.

Your query is also using a temporary table for a single select result, which is also often an indication that you're doing things wrong.

In your case, you should use a set-based join, remove the temp table, and select direct-to-output the results. The query would be something like:

```
with SubSeries as (

    SELECT Ser_Nazwa,Mag_GidNumer,Mag_Kod
    FROM CDN.Serie, CDN.Magazyny
    WHERE Mag_Kod in('1406','1407','1408')
    and SER_Nazwa like 's%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'sk%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'sa%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'st%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 'su%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's14/%' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's10' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's24' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's07' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's28' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's32' 
    and  SER_Nazwa not like 's61'

), SubZamNag as (

    SELECT ZaN_MagNumer,Zan_ZamSeria,Zan_DataRealizacji 
    FROM CDN.ZamNag 
    WHERE 
        DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) >= @dzisiaj
    AND DateAdd(day, ZaN_DataRealizacji,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1800-12-28',120)) <  @jutro

)
SELECT Ser_Nazwa as seria,
       Mag_Kod as magazynkod,
       case when exists(select 1
                        from SubZamNag
                        where Zan_MagNumer = Mag_GidNumer
                          and ZaN_ZamSeria = Ser_Nazwa
                        )
            then 'tak'
            else 'nie'
       end as zlozono,
       @dzisiaj as data
from SubSeries
```

Note the use of the [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms175972.aspx) to reduce the complexity of the final select.

There is no cursor needed, no temp table, and the operation is set-based.

Comment: hey from 1,30min to 15 seconds... I'm impressed.